# How do I write this in Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Thanks to Dave Bennett, I have a great Neo4j query that provides the results I need.  I need to get this to work in Neo4JClient.  Here's my working Neo4j query:

```
`// Composite Tile with related users
match (t:Tile{summary:"Test 1"})<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(u:User)
with {summary: t.summary,
        id:             t.id, 
        sprint_id:      t.sprint_id, 
        size:           t.size,
        percent_done:   t.percent_done,
        color:          t.color_id,
        description:    t.description,
        queue_id:       t.queue_id,
        swimlane_id:    t.swimlane_id,
        icons:          t.icons, 
        order:          t.order,
        assignees: collect(u)} as tile
RETURN collect(tile) as tiles`
```

Visual Studio and/or Neo4jClient is not very happy with my attempt:

```
var compositeTile = client.Cypher
                .Match("(t:Tile)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(u:User)")
                .Where((Tile t)=> t.summary == tile.summary)
                .With( {
                        summary:        t.summary, 
                        id:             t.id, 
                        sprint_id:      t.sprint_id,
                        size:           t.size,
                        percent_done:   tile.percent_done,
                        color:          t.color,
                        description:    t.description, 
                        queue_id:       t.queue_id, 
                        swimlane_id:    t.swimlane_id,
                        icons:          t.icons, 
                        Order:          t.order,
                        assignees:      collect(u)
                       } as tile)
                .return collect(tile) as tiles;
```

It just throws lots of red squiggly lines, I suspect because I'm not formatting the .with statement correctly.  I haven't been able to find an example, so I'm asking here. How do I do this correctly in Neo4jClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two answers to your question - the first is that the `.With` statement takes a string as a parameter, so you just need to wrap your text with `"` (or `@"` if you want to keep the formatting). The second answer is more of a problem for you though:

It's not possible to do what you're trying to do with `Neo4jClient` - at the moment it doesn't allow you to create anonymous types. It's not able to deserialize the content. I thought it might be a quick fix, but it seems like it would be more involved. So, what we're looking at here is a change of the query.

I presume you have a class called `Tile` with the properties you're after. So *I* would change the query to something like this:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(t:Tile)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(u:User)")
    .Where((Tile t) => t.summary == tile.summary)
    .Return((t,u) => new { 
        Tile = t.As<Tile>(),
        User = u.CollectAs<User>()
    });
```

Which will give you a C# anonymous type with a Tile and an `IEnumerable<Node<User>>` elements, obviously you want the `Users` in your `Tile`, so you can then parse the result:

```
var tiles = new List<Tile>();
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var tile = result.Tile;
    foreach (var user in result.Users)
        tile.users.Add(user.Data);
    tiles.Add(tile);
}
```

One thing you might find is that you need to initialize the `Users` collection, so either add `Users = new List<User>()` to your `Tile` constructor, or just before parsing the data.

Comment: Thanks for a patient and understandable answer.  I read the Neo4jClient Readify under Cypher and found the CollectAs function.  I ended up with the very same query, so you confirm that I'm getting this right.   Also the parsing was a big help.  I'm new to both C# and Neo4j, so the completeness of your answer is helpful.